# Merge up similar records fields where NaN in a dataframe

Tags: pandas, python-3.8

As an example I have a set of records like this:

```
   A    B    C    D
0  1    0    Nan  Nan
1  1    1    1    Nan
2  1    2    2    2
3  2    Nan  3    3
4  2    4    4    4
5  3    5    Nan  Nan
```

and I want to merge up all the records on Column A so that the later records will only replace previous if `Nan` is there. So that I end up like this:

```
   A    B    C    D
0  1    0    1    2
1  2    4    3    3
2  3    5    Nan  Nan
```

So I can do this already using `groupby()`, `iterrows()` and multiple passes until nothing remains, but it feels horribly inefficient.

I am curious if Pandas has a better way to do this before I start writing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `first`

```
#df = df.replace({'Nan':np.nan})

df = df.groupby('A', as_index=False).first()
df
Out[20]: 
   A    B    C    D
0  1  0.0  1.0  2.0
1  2  4.0  3.0  3.0
2  3  5.0  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: That worked. The replace helped as well, because the source data had `"Nan"` instead of a blank field value.